# Vim-airline maxline symbol overlaps with % symbol

Tags: neovim, vim-airline

I am currently using `vim-airline` with `Neovim 0.5.0` for writing small programs although it bothers me that the % symbol and ≡ symbol overlaps with each other at the bottom right.

An example is:

[image]

Resizing the window does not help. Is there a way to resize that exact part of the bar so that these two symbols do not converge?

Answer (score 4):

You can try `let g:airline_symbols.colnr = ' '`.

I previously suffered exactly the same problem as you, and I worked it out with the solution above.

I hope this works. Actually, the ' %:' is the *column* symbol, the *maxline* symbol occupies two spaces, thus overlapping with the symbol *%*.

Comment: This seems like a good answer! I have switched to linux now though (not because of this issue) and I've not had this issue ever since so I can't really mark this answer as solved if I can't test it. Thanks for trying!

Comment: I had to add in an extra check `if !exists('g:airline_symbols')` before it would work for me. Setting it to a value if it did not exist with `let g:airline_symbols = {}`.

Sourced from [Github Issue #2381](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/2381#issuecomment-940825425).

Comment: I had this issue as well, but only with the special unicode symbols. I basically just added appropriate spacing to make it readable. So for example I edited those symbols to have spaces in them (" X "), like so: let g:airline_symbols.colnr = ' ☰ '. using that principle I customized all the symbols to how I wanted them. For example I used that row symbol but for the columns I used: let g:airline_symbols.colnr = ' Ⅲ '